# loop through subfolder and delete certain file name out of zip folder

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

need a little guidance here.
what I'm trying to do is loop through a directory of zip files. and delete any file that matches a certain naming convention.

Since I'm not familiar with the for /D /r loop. I need some help.  I just don't understand the loop when reading articles on it.  [for loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)

mission in the loop.
set zip file name variable then run

```
7z d "C:\temp\%zipfile%" *Telephone* -r
```

Comment: There are examples in the article you mentioned, do you not understand them? What exactly do you not understand? What kind of naming convention is that?

Comment: Not understanding why you think you need to use `/D /R`.  That will enumerate folder names and not zip files.  You just want to use `/R`. `FOR /R %%G IN (*.zip) DO 7z d "%%G" *Telephone* -r`

Comment: I just don't know how to apply the loop and I'm not understanding the parameter %%G  See I have tons of Zip files that I need to iterate through in one directory. In the do section, I have more than just that telephone value to delete. like files with Travel in them and outreach. I have over 16 certain file types that I need to remove. Plus I need to include a rename process as well.

Comment: I was able to figure it out. thanks for your help.